# unwanted line break in email header when using email.mime

Tags: python, mime, mime-message

I'm playing around with SMTP and using email.mime to provide the header structure. For some reason when a try to add a header that exceeds a certain length a line break is added into my header line.

e.g.

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
message = 'some message'
msg = MIMEText(message)
msg.add_header('some header', 'just wondering why this sentence is continually cut in half for a reason I can not find')

print msg['some header']
print msg
```

print msg['some header'] prints:-

```
some header: just wondering just wondering why this sentence is continually cut in half for a reason I can not find
```

print msg prints:-

```
some header: just wondering why this sentence is continually cut in half for a
 reason I can not find
```

One thing I did discover is that the length at which it's cut off is a combination of the header title and its value. So when I shorted 'some header' to 'some', the line return changes to after 'reason' instead of before.

It's not just my viewing page width :), it actually sends the email with the new line character in the email header.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct behaviour, and it's the `email` package that does this (as well as most of the email generating code out there.) RFC822 messages (and all successors to that standard) have a way of continuing headers so they don't have to be a single line. It's considered good practice to fold headers like that, and the tab character that indents the rest of the header's body means the header is continued.

Comment: See also: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt Section 2.1.1 describes the recommended line length of 78 characters, and Section 2.2.3 describes line "folding".

Comment: @thomas Thanks for the quick reply. Is there a way to override the email package so it doesn't force a new line?

Comment: The only real way, I believe, would be to instantiate `email.header.Header` directly, or replace `email.header.MAXLINELEN` with a larger value. I suggest not doing this, though. What the `email` package is generated is entirely compliant and the encouraged format. Perhaps you should not be doing the thing that requires that messages are represented in equivalent but different formats.